# CentOS 7 lighttpd startup failed

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, lighttpd

I'm running CentOS 7 and when I start lighttpd, it showed status `[OK]`, but when I check the status, it does not actually run. There isn't much information on the startup log, but here is it:

```
[root@km15501 lighttpd]# service lighttpd status
● lighttpd.service - Lightning Fast Webserver With Light System Requirements
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2016-03-15 02:19:11 CET; 6s ago
  Process: 8583 ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 8583 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

Mar 15 02:19:11 km15501.servernode.de systemd[1]: Started Lightning Fast Webserver With Light System Requirements.
Mar 15 02:19:11 km15501.servernode.de systemd[1]: Starting Lightning Fast Webserver With Light System Requirements...
Mar 15 02:19:11 km15501.servernode.de systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Mar 15 02:19:11 km15501.servernode.de systemd[1]: Unit lighttpd.service entered failed state.
Mar 15 02:19:11 km15501.servernode.de systemd[1]: lighttpd.service failed.
[root@km15501 lighttpd]
```

Has anyone faced this problem before? I tried to change the port from 81 to 8080/8081, but it didn't work.

**UPDATE:**

I ran:

```
/usr/local/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

Result:

```
Aborted
```

I ran:

```
 strace  /usr/local/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

Result:

```
execve("/usr/local/sbin/lighttpd", ["/usr/local/sbin/lighttpd", "-D", "-f", "/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf"], [/* 23 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xd3f000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc2670c000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=63292, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 63292, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc266fc000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpcre.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=398272, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2490888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc2628b000
mprotect(0x7fbc262eb000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc264ea000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5f000) = 0x7fbc264ea000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19520, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc26087000
mprotect(0x7fbc2608a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc26289000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fbc26289000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\6\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=6928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc266fb000
mmap(NULL, 2101312, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc25e85000
mprotect(0x7fbc25e86000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc26085000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc26085000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\246\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1287944, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3368432, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc25b4e000
mprotect(0x7fbc25c83000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc25e82000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x134000) = 0x7fbc25e82000
mmap(0x7fbc25e84000, 1520, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc25e84000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=44096, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2128952, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc25946000
mprotect(0x7fbc2594d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc25b4c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7fbc25b4c000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240l\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=142304, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc266fa000
mmap(NULL, 2208864, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc2572a000
mprotect(0x7fbc25740000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc25940000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7fbc25940000
mmap(0x7fbc25942000, 13408, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc25942000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2107816, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3932736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc25369000
mprotect(0x7fbc2551f000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc2571f000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b6000) = 0x7fbc2571f000
mmap(0x7fbc25725000, 16960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc25725000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc266f9000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc266f7000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fbc266f7740) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc2571f000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc25940000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc25b4c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc25e82000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc26085000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc26289000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc264ea000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x637000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc2670d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fbc266fc000, 63292)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7fbc266f7a10)         = 16832
set_robust_list(0x7fbc266f7a20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7fbc25730780, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7fbc25730810, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xd3f000
brk(0xd60000)                           = 0xd60000
brk(0)                                  = 0xd60000
getuid()                                = 0
getcwd("/etc/lighttpd", 1087)           = 14
stat("/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6396, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf", O_RDONLY) = 3
mmap(NULL, 6396, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc2670a000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fbc2670a000, 6396)            = 0
open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY)             = 3
close(0)                                = 0
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY)             = 3
close(1)                                = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/var/www/vhosts/youdive.eu/httpdocs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/www/vhosts/youdive.eu/httpdocs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/VAR/WWW/VHOSTS/YOUDIVE.EU/HTTPDOCS", 0x7fff464fee70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0x7fbc2628a0d0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_indexfile.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=40885, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2105560, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc25166000
mprotect(0x7fbc25168000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc25367000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7fbc25367000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc25367000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_access.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\v\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=40348, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2105488, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24f63000
mprotect(0x7fbc24f65000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc25164000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7fbc25164000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc25164000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_simple_vhost.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\r\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=41645, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2105536, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24d60000
mprotect(0x7fbc24d62000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24f61000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7fbc24f61000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24f61000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_secdownload.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=46386, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109672, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24b5c000
mprotect(0x7fbc24b5f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24d5e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fbc24d5e000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24d5e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_flv_streaming.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=48258, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109704, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24958000
mprotect(0x7fbc2495a000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24b5a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fbc24b5a000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24b5a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_h264_streaming.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\32\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=334898, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2167496, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24746000
mprotect(0x7fbc24757000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24956000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10000) = 0x7fbc24956000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24956000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_accesslog.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\24\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=59433, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2113904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24541000
mprotect(0x7fbc24545000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24744000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7fbc24744000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24744000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_dirlisting.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\31\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=73805, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2118376, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc2433b000
mprotect(0x7fbc24340000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc2453f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7fbc2453f000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc2453f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_staticfile.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \24\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=52229, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109792, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24137000
mprotect(0x7fbc2413a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24339000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fbc24339000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24339000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_chunked.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\17\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=46895, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109672, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc23f33000
mprotect(0x7fbc23f35000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24135000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fbc24135000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24135000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/var/run/lighttpd.pid", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_TRUNC, 0644) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
stat("/var/run/lighttpd.pid", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6, ...}) = 0
open("/var/run/lighttpd.pid", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644) = 3
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=4*1024}) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 4
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8080), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(4, 1024)                         = 0
getgid()                                = 0
getuid()                                = 0
write(3, "16832\n", 6)                  = 6
close(3)                                = 0
open("/var/log/lighttpd/access.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0644) = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
open("/var/log/lighttpd/error.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0644) = 5
fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
write(5, "log.c.142: (trace) server starte"..., 35) = 35
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY)             = 6
close(2)                                = 0
dup2(6, 2)                              = 2
close(6)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x409c00, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x409c00, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x409c00, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x409c00, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x409c00, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x409c00, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xd60000
brk(0xd83000)                           = 0xd83000
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc23732000
mprotect(0x7fbc23732000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fbc23f31fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fbc23f329d0, tls=0x7fbc23f32700, child_tidptr=0x7fbc23f329d0) = 16833
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc22f31000
mprotect(0x7fbc22f31000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fbc23730fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fbc237319d0, tls=0x7fbc23731700, child_tidptr=0x7fbc237319d0) = 16834
futex(0x7fbc25e84488, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)    = 1
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc22730000
mprotect(0x7fbc22730000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fbc22f2ffb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fbc22f309d0, tls=0x7fbc22f30700, child_tidptr=0x7fbc22f309d0) = 16835
futex(0x7fbc25e84488, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)    = 1
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc21f2f000
mprotect(0x7fbc21f2f000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fbc2272efb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fbc2272f9d0, tls=0x7fbc2272f700, child_tidptr=0x7fbc2272f9d0) = 16836
futex(0x7fbc25e84488, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)    = 1
mmap(NULL, 69632, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc266e6000
mprotect(0x7fbc266e6000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fbc266f5fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fbc266f69d0, tls=0x7fbc266f6700, child_tidptr=0x7fbc266f69d0) = 16837
futex(0x7fbc25e84488, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)    = 1
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
write(2, "Attempt to unlock mutex that was"..., 44) = 44
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
tgkill(16832, 16832, SIGABRT)           = 0
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=16832, si_uid=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGABRT +++
Aborted
```

[My lighttpd.conf is here](http://pastebin.com/jRYSef2W).

Answer (score 0):

To open ports in CentOS 7 make sure that `firewalld` is running, if not start `firewalld` using this command `systemctl start firewalld`.

The following command will open port 8080 for TCP traffic, for the current session only:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp
```

If wanted to persist this on reboot:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
```

Then reload:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Then verify if it is already open:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
```

Please see this [link](http://www.linuxbrigade.com/centos-7-rhel-7-open-ports/) for more information.

Comment: thanks for the answer, after some digging with the strace result "Attempt to unlock mutex that was" look like something to do with glibc and gtk.. dont think it was caused by firewall.